# Compiling error with stacks declarations

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors, stack, calculator

So I'm new to java and I'm trying to make a calculator with some typical error controls but I can't seem to get it working and I'm kinda stuck. I'd really appreciate some help on whats causing the breakdown. The compiler gives me this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at ergasia.ioanna.ErgasiaIoanna.check(ErgasiaIoanna.java:38)
at ergasia.ioanna.ErgasiaIoanna.main(ErgasiaIoanna.java:101)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

---

```
package ergasia.ioanna;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ErgasiaIoanna {

    static void praksi(Stack telestes,Stack arithmoi){
    double res;
    Character temp = (Character) telestes.pop();
    Double ar2 = (Double) arithmoi.pop();
    Double ar1 = (Double) arithmoi.pop();
    if(temp=='+'){
        res=ar1+ar2;
    }
     if(temp=='-'){
        res=ar1-ar2;
    }
     if(temp=='*'){
        res=ar1*ar2;
    }
     if(temp=='/'){
        if(ar2==0){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        else{
            res=ar1/ar2;
        }
    }
     if(temp=='^'){
        res=Math.pow(ar1,ar2);
    }
        arithmoi.push( new Double (res) );

    }
    static void check(char i,Stack telestes,Stack arithmoi){
        int error=0;
        char cha = (Character) telestes.peek();
        double ar = (Double) arithmoi.peek();
        if(i==')'){
           if(telestes.empty() || cha=='('){
               System.out.println("error");
               error=1;
           }
           do{
               praksi(telestes,arithmoi);
               cha=(char) telestes.peek();
               if(telestes.empty()){
                 System.out.println("error");
                 cha='(';
               }
           }while(cha!='(');
        }
        if(i=='='){
            while(!telestes.empty()){
                praksi(telestes,arithmoi);
                cha = (Character) telestes.peek();
            }
           System.out.print(arithmoi.pop());
        }
        if(i=='+' || i=='-'){
            if(!telestes.empty() || cha!='('){
                praksi(telestes,arithmoi);
                telestes.push(i);
            }
            else{
               telestes.push(i);
            }
        }
        if(i=='*' || i=='/'){
            if(cha=='^'){
             praksi(telestes,arithmoi);
               telestes.push(i);  
            }
            else{
                telestes.push(i);
            }
        }
        if(i=='^'){
            if(!telestes.empty() || cha!='('){
                praksi(telestes,arithmoi);
                telestes.push(i);
        }
        else{
            telestes.push(i);
        }

    }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        Stack Tel = new Stack();
        Stack Ar = new Stack();
        char c;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do {
         c = (char) br.read();
         check(c,Tel,Ar);
      } while(c != 's');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not compile error. This is runtime error from your program. Add some debug prints or run your program through a debugger to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `java.util.EmptyStackException` means that you are attempting an operation, in this case `peek` on an empty stack.  In your `main` method, you declare two `Stack`s `Tel` and `Ar`. which both start out empty.  You then pass those empty stacks to your `check` method, which attempts to `peek` at their first element, which is when you get the `EmptyStackException`.